# Finding velocity field components from electric and magnetic field components in ideal MHD

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, astrophysics, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

How can I determine the components of the velocity field ($V_x, V_y, V_z$) using the components of the electric field $(E_x, E_y, E_z)$ and magnetic field $(B_x, B_y, B_z)$, assuming the ideal magnetohydrodynamics (MHD) equation
$$\vec{E} = -\vec{V} \times \vec{B},$$
and the condition $$\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B} = 0.$$ I have attempted to estimate the determinant of this system, but it yields zero. Are there any additional constraints or methods that I may have overlooked?

Comment: Why do you need the velocity field? Shouldn't that be something given in the initial conditions and you find the time-evolution after?

Comment: Thinking about it some, an extension of my comment is really, "What is it you are actually trying to solve?" Obviously the velocity somehow plays a role in what you're looking for, but I think it'd be useful for a few extra details about the actual goal you've set for yourself.

Comment: I am actually considering experimental data from spacecraft measurements in the solar wind.

Comment: Hmm. Shouldn't velocity/speed and magnetic field be the measured values in such an instrument? I'm familiar with things like [Solar Ham](https://www.solarham.net/solarwind.htm) that show $B$, $v$, $T$ and $\rho$ measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the cross product equation is a well known problem. You can prove that if $\mathbf P=\mathbf Q\times \mathbf X$ (and $\mathbf P\cdot \mathbf Q =0)$ for vectors $\mathbf P,\mathbf Q$ and unknown vector $\mathbf X$, then you have that
$$\mathbf X=\frac{\mathbf P\times \mathbf Q}{|\mathbf Q|}+k \mathbf Q$$
where $k$ is a scalar that has to be determined from another equation. You are right to have a zero determinant, you can see that the solution above works for any value of $k$.

The equations of ideal magnetohydrodynamics (MHD) are actually more than 2, you are probably missing other common fluid equations like:

1. the conservation of mass $\partial_t\rho+\nabla\cdot(\rho \mathbf V)=0$
2. the conservation of momentum $\partial_t  (\rho \mathbf V)+\nabla\cdot (\rho \mathbf V \otimes \mathbf V)=-\nabla P +\text{other force terms}$
3. An equation for the energy or for pressure $P$

You will also need boundary/initial conditions and fluid properties to completely determine your system.

Note also that the equation $\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf B=0$ is not always true in ideal MHD, so you should check the hypotheses you are considering.

Comment: In this case is there a way to impose a constrain for k through another equation that I am missing?

Comment: @Jokerp yes, this cannot be solved completely using just those two equations.

Comment: Thanks that is good answer. However, I am still missing the other equation i could use. I have upvoted but it's not exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Jokerp it is up to you to provide more details. What kind of problem are you solving, edit your question to add more context.

Comment: The context is  the equations of ideal MHD. You start from Ohm's law and assume infinite conductivity so you get the first equation I wrote int the question.

Comment: @Jokerp I have expanded on the ideal MHD equations